# Pygame Is Installed On Ubuntu 18.04, But Can't Use In Itellij

Tags: 18.04, python3, intellij

I'm trying to make a game with pygame. I managed to install pygame and python 3.8 today. But Intellij won't recognize the package or let me install it. I got an error from `import pygame` that says `No module named pygame`

```
:~$ python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
Collecting pygame
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/24/ede6428359f913ed9cd1643dd5533aefeb5a2699cc95bea089de50ead586/pygame-1.9.6-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6
:~$ python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

But I get this message when I try to install pygame in intellij

```
     https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pycharm-packaging/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-g85mo6rw
       cwd: /tmp/pycharm-packaging/pygame/
 <Lines Omitted For Brevity>
src_c/_pygame.h:85:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
         #include <Python.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Is the package `libpython3.8-dev` installed?

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I tried many other suggestions from online pertaining to intellij errors with pygame, but none of them worked. https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-amd64/libpython3.8-dev_3.8.0-3~18.04_amd64.deb.html

Comment: This wasn't a pygame issue per se; what happened was you installed it with python3.6 (with `libpython3.6-dev` package probably already installed) and Intellij uses python3.8.

Comment: how do you guys know all this stuff? I'm not sure how I installed it. I just find a forum, if the comments look promising I try the terminal commands until something works. Yes, I was doing some educational stuff last year with 3.6, and didn't use python for a while, and now it's 3.8, and trying to update I guess that caused my problems.

Comment: I ran into "file-not-found errors" many times when I first learned python, and soon discovered `apt-file`. I also learned that separate versions of python have separate libraries/modules; this is a good thing.

Comment: I downloaded `apt-file`. What am I supposed to be looking for in Python and Pygame with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113450/discussion-between-ajgringo619-and-user2904033).